# Ubuntu 18.04 keeps enlarging my display resolution after exiting full screen

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, acer, multiple-monitors

Maybe I'm just a numnut who doesn't know how to use Ubuntu (I'm fairly new to it), but I've gone looking through other askubuntu pages and there are many similar to my current problem, but none actually fix it.

Sometimes, whenever I exit full screen, my monitor's resolution is shrunk to 1280x720 from 1920x1080. I have two monitors, one is Acer and the other is ViewSonic, but the resolution change only affects the Acer. I can quickly change it back to the original resolution, but I'd rather it didn't happen at all.

Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEyk9.jpg) to show you the difference in resolution. It's been altered to hide any personal info.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! can you edit your question and add the output from `sudo lshw -class video` ?? this will help us help you :)

Comment: What are you existing fullscreen from?

Comment: Also please note that the resolution 1280x720 is *smaller* than 1920x1080, despite it appearing "bigger" because of being stretched.

Comment: @KristopherIves It's only ever happened when I exit Youtube's fullscreen player

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte Sorry, I'm still new to all of this and don't know how to add an output